# powershell: how to execute commands on server and let server keep the output information?

Tags: powershell

I am running powershell command on my local machine to start a batch file on remote server. However, the server always returns the echo outputs of the batch file to my local machine, which is not what i want.
Can we execute commands on server and let server keep the output information?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Invoke command?

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName machinename -ScriptBlock {ipconfig > C:\temp.txt}
```

Comment: Thanks! yes, tried, doesn't work. it always outputs to local machine

Comment: What if you give a UNC path as an output?

Comment: sorry i made a mistake. the command you posted here works well, and can save the temp.txt file to remote server.

Comment: i ran a batch file  on the remote machine, it should start a command window and output log information on the remote server. however, it never start the cmd windows on server, instead, it outputs the log information on my local powshell command window.

Comment: Could you post sample of your batch file, maybe we can change something around

Comment: invoke-command -computer $serverip -scriptblock{param($par1) D:\test.bat $par1} -ArgumentList $zkhost

Comment: I believe you are missing the ">" after your D:\test.bat, that is how you output to whatever $par1 is

Comment: No, the $par is the parameter for the bat file, not the output file name.

Comment: This works:
Invoke-Command -ComputerName myServer -ScriptBlock{C:\temp\ipconfig.bat > C:\temp\ip.txt}

This will store the ip.txt file in temp drive of "myServer"